# Django command without Django application?

Tags: django, django-commands

Is there any way I can add a custom Django command which doesn't need an underlying application or project to work (pretty much like `startapp` or `startproject`)?

`$ django-admin.py startveryniceproject projectname`

One way I can imagine this could be accomplished would be to copy a `startveryniceproject.py` into `django.core.management.commands`, but does that really sound "clean"?

Comment: What would you hope to achieve by this? You couldn't do very much without a settings file, which is the minimum required for a project anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Maybe "alias" `django-admin.py startproject --template=/path/to/something --and-some-options" with `django-admin.py startveryniceproject`.